# Parsing a SQL Server string into substrings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column of data I've imported form a lotus notes database which consists of a contacted address field. The items in the address are separated by ASCII (13), ASCII (10)

What the easiest way to split this address up in to separate columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like this in my projects. Unfortunatly I don't have my optimized version at hand but I coded it down quickly. This might get you started...

```
CREATE FUNCTION fx_Split
(
    @text varchar(max),
    @splitChar char(1)
)
RETURNS 
@Result TABLE 
(
    RowIndex int identity(1,1),
    SplitText varchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @index int SET @index = 0
    DECLARE @SplitText varchar(max) SET @SplitText = ''
    DECLARE @TempText varchar(max) SET @SplitText = ''

    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@splitChar, @text) 
    SET @TempText = @text

    WHILE(@index > 0)
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @Result VALUES (SUBSTRING(@TempText, 1, @index-1))

        SET @TempText = SUBSTRING(@TempText, @index + 1, LEN(@TempText))

        SET @index = CHARINDEX(@splitChar, @TempText) 

    END 

    INSERT INTO @Result VALUES (@TempText)

    RETURN 
END
GO


select * from dbo.fx_Split ('asdf,qwer,asfegqgr,qweqwefe,qwf4ggrr,qfasdglsdfg', ',')
```